# Hovering Multiple Divs when targeting one

Tags: html, css

Hello Stack Overflow Pros

Id like to hover multiple divs when i hover the image.
There is a nav bar on top of different images, when i hover the 
image i want to trigger the navigation above.

Here some code:

You can see that the nav is underlined. I want it to trigger, when i clicking on the image.

Thanks a lot for your help!

```css
#nav_start_container {

 float:left;
 position:relative;
 margin-left:60px;


}

#nav_start_container ul li {
    min-width:136px;
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 margin:0;

}


.nav_start  { 

    min-width:136px;
 display: inline-block;
 color: #495d7f;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: 550;
 margin-bottom:20px;
 text-align:center;
}

.nav_start:hover {
    
 text-decoration: underline;
 background: #fff !important;
 color: #495d7f;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;

}

#current {
text-decoration: underline !important;
 background: #fff !important;
 color: #495d7f !important;
 
}

.bannerbild {
margin:0;
}


.bannerbild:hover {

padding-top:7px;
position:absolute;


}
```

```html
 <div id="nav_start_container">
 <ul id="nav">
 
  <li>
        <a href="portrait.html">
              <span class="nav_start">test2</span>
              <img src="images/1a.jpg" alt="…" class="bannerbild" />
        </a>
     </li>
   <li>
        <a href="portrait.html">
              <span class="nav_start">test2</span>
              <img src="images/1b.jpg" alt="…" class="bannerbild" />
        </a>
     </li>
    <li>
        <a href="portrait.html">
              <span class="nav_start">test2</span>
              <img src="images/1c.jpg" alt="…" class="bannerbild" />
        </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="portrait.html">
              <span class="nav_start">test2</span>
              <img src="images/1d.jpg" alt="…" class="bannerbild" />
        </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="portrait.html">
              <span class="nav_start">test2</span>
              <img src="images/1e.jpg" alt="…" class="bannerbild" />
        </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="portrait.html">
              <span class="nav_start">test2</span>
              <img src="images/1f.jpg" alt="…" class="bannerbild" />
        </a>
     </li>
 
  
  
 </ul>



  
    <div class="clear"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle.

Comment: sure : http://jsfiddle.net/erd6q21m/ thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the required elements for each menu item in the link.

```
  <li>
        <a href="test2.html">
              <span class="link-text">test2</span>
              <img src="images/1b.jpg" alt="…" class="banner-image" />
        </a>
  </li>
```

Now, if you set an `:hover` definition to the link, it will work if you mouse over the link text or the image. You also shouldn't repeat all the main navigation links (they will be read twice by assistive technologies and search engine bots…)

Comment: thanks man - is it possible to set it up that if i hover the image that both (link-text) is hovered BUT if i hover the text - only the text gets hovered ?

Comment: ive cleaned the code - thanks for the advice - but still no clue how i can hover both when hovering the image